# IE's execCommand not working when inserting image

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using nicedit WYWIWYG editor and all is well in the land of the good web browser but once again MS has cause me frustration through its IE incarnation!

For some reason this command

```
document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
```

is returning false unlike all other browsers, therefore not executing properly

These are my params:

```
    cmd "insertImage"   String
    args    "javascript:nicImTemp();"   String
```

Anyone shed any light? I've ensured that the "allow scripting of Microsoft web browser control" is enabled in the security settings

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As an XSS-attack-surface-reduction, Internet Explorer 6 and later do not permit a "javascript:" URL as the source of an IMG tag. Specify a HTTP/HTTPS/FILE URI instead and your code should work.

Comment: This actually made no difference Im afraid even with a standard string

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 you have to put focus() on your editing area first.

Comment: it is already, thats how the user activates the bar, but I guess it could be loosing it, I will try it when I next try